# 2darray indexing in numpy, python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to index N values in a NxM numpy array, 1 in each row. The Indices are ordered in a list.

The way to normally index a multidimensional array is

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
a[2,3] # 11
```

for multiple indices:

```
a[[1,1],[0,2]] # array([4,6])
```

So, for my question, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
i = [1,2,1]
a[np.arange(3), i] # array([1,6,9])
```

I'm wondering if the row indices can be given in an implicit way. I thought that the semicolon operator would help out, but it gives me the complete columns.

Comment: what is the question? ... whether you can write the last line in your code without `np.arange`?

Comment: yes, [`np.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) appears to be the solution. Thanks to @ajcr for recognizing the duplicate.